# How should a UDP server reply to its clients?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, udp

I need a UDP server that can communicate with many clients.

My current thinking is

1. open a socket
2. bind to a port
3. recvfrom the client
4. fork

   - child: process the message, open a new socket and sendto the client
   - parent: go to step 3

The server replies to the client on the same port from which the client connected, but from a random port.

I've implemented this, and with my test client, it works.

However, the real client is being written by someone else, somewhere else. (It's an embedded system)

His client is expecting a reply from the same port to which he sent the message. The only way I can seem to do this is by using the same socket, which does work.

My worry though, is that will cause problems if more than one client tries to connect at once.

How should this be done?

Comment: Why forking and opening a new socket?  Just reply on the same socket in the same thread.

Comment: Looks like I was trying to overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDP sockets are much simpler then TCP ones. Just reply on the same socket with [**`sendto(2)`**](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendto.2.html) with client address you got from [**`recvfrom(2)`**](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recvfrom.2.html). No need to mess this threads, just do it in a loop.

#### Edit 0:

To elaborate a bit after your comment - when you get a datagram on a UDP socket you don't get a new socket descriptor like with TCP, so your parent still handles all the input. Now, do you plan on `fork(2)`-ing a new process and then creating a new socket for every packet? Or do you want to keep track of source addresses and map them to child processes and setup some sort of message passing from parent to child? I wouldn't do either. The overhead is just too great. Just do it inline.

Then if your message rates are *really* high and your processing is *really* heavy - increase server socket receive buffer (`SO_RCVBUF`, [**`setsockopt(2)`**](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html)), look into threading your server splitting it into I/O and processing parts, look into lock-free queuing, etc. But that last part is a whole different story. Start simple.

Comment: Won't that cause the server to block while it's processing a client?  I'm not sure if that would realistically cause a problem though.

Comment: If your message rates are really high, the simplest thing to do is simply `fork()` (or `pthread_create()`) several servers, that all block on `recvfrom()` and have exactly the same code.  The kernel will only wake one of them for each recieved packet.

Comment: Hmm, yes and no. This gives too much control to the kernel in my opinion. Also if you need to keep track of source sequencing this won't fly without some additional overhead.

Comment: @caf Dedicating a thread to each connection is not generally very efficient, especially if you don't make a pool of them.

Comment: @black: My comment wasn't to suggest one thread or process per connection.  It was in reply to Johan's comment about the server blocking while processing a client, in the context of the answer suggesting looping around answering the client in the same thread that received the query.  My comment is meaning to suggest that you can simply have N threads or processes doing that loop at all times, if your message rates are high - but certainly *not* creating one thread or process per client.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to either fork or create a new socket to send to the client. You can and should do everything with a single socket.